# Write a new column to existing xlsx file

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I have an `.xlsx` file with a basic format of across multiple sheets (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3)

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5
abc1 | abc2 | abc3 | abc4 | abc5
```

Where the number of columns varies. I want to be able to write a new given a sheet's name. At the minute I have:

```
import openpyxl


def get_sheets():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/mydir/Desktop/myfile.xlsx')
    sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()

sheet3 = "Sheet3"
sheet4 = "Sheet4"
for i in sheets:
    if i == sheet3:
        # Write column
    elif i == sheet4:
        # Write column in different sheet
    else:
        continue


def main():
    get_sheets()

    print
    print "Script finished."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Does openpyxl allow a new column to be written to an existing xlsx file with a header and rows equalling the number of rows after the header?

Comment: This code does almost nothing.

Comment: @CharlieClark the code does what it's supposed to do at the minute, gets a 
two particular sheet from an xlsx with multiple sheets. The comments in the code are where I want to write a new column in that sheet.

Comment: I see no code trying to write a cell, just some pseudo-code for branching. What part of the library don't you understand.

Comment: So you're saying the library has been updated from your answer here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/wHGecdQg3Iw. Searching your documenation http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/ doesn't provide any clear answers either.

Comment: That's a completely different question: inserting a column of data in an existing sheet. Please edit the question so that it is clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add a new column to an existing xlsx file, you could write an `add_column()` function as follows. This takes the sheet name and a list of values that you wish to add:

```
import openpyxl

def add_column(sheet_name, column):
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    new_column = ws.max_column + 1
    
    for rowy, value in enumerate(column, start=1):
        ws.cell(row=rowy, column=new_column, value=value)


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/mydir/Desktop/myfile.xlsx')
add_column('Sheet3', ['new header', 'value1', 'value2'])
wb.save('output.xlsx')   # use the same name if required
```

You can get the worksheet by name simply by using `wb['Sheet3']`. Then to get the number of existing columns in the worksheet use `ws.max_column` to get the last column index. Add `1` for your newly appended column.

Next use Python's [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function to work through the list of column values. For each it gives you the row number to use and the value to write to the cell.